# Why does Data want to be human?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data, androids

If Data cannot be happy or sad, why does he try to be more human and is wanting an emotion?

Comment: Hi. I note you haven't accepted any answers for this question yet. If my answer addresses the question, would you please consider answering it for future viewers? If not, please let me know where I can improve it!

Comment: Pinocchio complex.

Answer (score 26):

## Because Data's purpose was to be more than the sum of his programming

The [Memory Alpha page on Data](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Data#Human_development) contains a few useful pieces of information:

> "I chose to believe that I was a person, that I had the potential to
>   become more than a collection of circuits and sub-processors." – Data,
>   2369 ("Rightful Heir")

and

> Data asserted that he did not only perceive data and facts, but also
>   the "substance" and "flavor" and other ineffable qualities of the
>   experience, which would be lost when downloaded to a conventional
>   computer. (TNG: "The Measure Of A Man")

The context of that first quote though is much more revealing:

> DATA: Yes. The Starfleet officers who first activated me on Omicron
>   Theta told me I was an android, nothing more than a sophisticated
>   machine with human form. However **I realised that if I were simply a
>   machine, I could never be anything else. I could never grow beyond my
>   programming. I found that difficult to accept, so I chose to believe
>   that I was a person, that I had the potential to be more than a
>   collection of circuits and subprocessors. It is a belief which I still
>   hold.**

Hence, his desire to *grow beyond his programming* is what makes Data strive towards becoming more human.

Emotions are only one facet of humans; Data acknowledges that he was not merely a machine, but a being with capacities far exceeding a normal machine.  Many of his qualities, especially his appearance, were already human.  He wanted to go beyond the superficial, though, and become more human.  Note how Data has *friends*, notably Geordi; a **very** human quality.  Data doesn't need emotions necessarily to form a friendship, so in this aspect he can become more human without the emotion chip.

Comment: Question: was Data programmed to try to be more than his programming? Wouldn't that mean he was still abiding by his programming?

Comment: @PointlessSpike: Phrasing it that way does make it sound silly.  Either Data is already quite good at phrasing things in a human way, or the writers missed that.  I think the obvious conclusion is that Data was designed / programmed to act / feel / be more than an emotionless AI.  Whether Noonian Soong's design was exactly what he intended or not, it's close enough that you can think of Data as a machine with these goals, or you can think of him as a person.  (Or both, if you don't have a problem with non-traditional personhood.)

Comment: And obviously the out-of-universe reason is that Trek always needs a character on the outside of humanity looking in.  Spock / Data / Odo / 7of9.  Pre-7of9, I don't remember Voyager playing this much.  There were non-human characters, but that wasn't the most important thing about any of them.  Early Voyager went for fitting in as non-Starfleet storylines, rather than as non-human.  (Neelix, and various Maquis.)

Comment: @PointlessSpike he wasn't *programmed* to be more than his programming; he was programmed to *develop*; in a sense it is no different to us; we are 'programmed' to find a purpose - to find a greater reason and through that we humans become more than our programming.  You seem to be confusing his *purpose* with his *programming*

Comment: @N_Soong: *programmed to develop* is the idea I was looking for in my earlier comment, but failed to come up with.

Comment: @N_Soong, We're not really programmed to find a purpose, though. Such thoughts are really just a malfunction of the human brain, a result of the peculiar way it works. Data would have to be programmed to do *something*, even if that *something* was to find his own purpose. No matter what, he's still abiding by his programming, whereas we are just all kinda broken.

Comment: @PointlessSpike I'd argue that we are; it seems to be a pretty common desire to want to be part of something larger.  Just my 2c.  Data was given the ability of choice, Soong mentions this in *Brothers*, so we know that it was his *choice* to seek out a particular purpose, but he was designed to make this choice as to what this purpose was.  The quote in my answer supports that this decision to become human was his own choice, but the desire to seek a purpose was programmed into him.

Comment: Are humans more than the sum of their programming? I know they *think* they are.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Describing anything as a malfunction means you're assuming the existence of an intended function that is going wrong somewhere.  Which is a concept I'm fine with, but I suspect it's not what you intended. Did you perhaps mean "behaviour?"

Comment: Happen to watch the episode where Data meets his mother and speaks to his father in the holo-deck. His mother reveals that Data was purposely made to be less human and without emotion because previous iterations that had emotion and were too human became unstable. It might support the case of questing for what's lost/forbidden/unattainable.